# Map reduce and Hbase on Dataproc

Tags: hadoop, hbase, google-cloud-dataproc

I am facing below error while executing Dataproc hadoop job. WIth some debugging I found that code is unable to get the HBASE Table.

`Error: java.io.IOException: Cannot create a record reader because of a previous error. Please look at the previous logs lines from the task's full log for more details.`

```
if (this.table == null) {
    throw new IOException("Cannot create a record reader because of a previous error. Please look at the previous logs lines from the task's full log for more details.");
}
```

Comment: I am running the same job on EMR and job is getting executed succesfully.

Comment: Well, `look at the previous logs lines from the task's full log for more details.` ... Can you share those log lines?

Comment: This is the guide for Spark, MapReduce should be similar https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/spark-hbase

Comment: Could you share your MapReduce code snippet and key configs in the question?

Comment: Can you share the code that you use to try to get the `HBASE` table?